# Android Analytics API V4 doesnt report data

Tags: android, sdk, google-analytics

What could cause analytics hit do not be sent to server? Here is my log

```
12-16 17:19:41.921  15731-15758/com.zapk.lsmods V/GAV4﹕ Thread[GAThread,5,main]: connecting to Analytics service
12-16 17:19:41.951  15731-15758/com.zapk.lsmods V/GAV4﹕ Thread[GAThread,5,main]: connect: bindService returned true for Intent { act=com.google.android.gms.analytics.service.START cmp=com.google.android.gms/.analytics.service.AnalyticsService (has extras) }

12-16 17:19:42.021  15731-15758/com.zapk.lsmods I/GAV4﹕ Thread[GAThread,5,main]: No campaign data found.
12-16 17:19:42.021  15731-15758/com.zapk.lsmods V/GAV4﹕ Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Initialized GA Thread
12-16 17:19:42.021  15731-15758/com.zapk.lsmods V/GAV4﹕ Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Loaded clientId
12-16 17:19:42.031  15731-15758/com.zapk.lsmods V/GAV4﹕ Thread[GAThread,5,main]: putHit called
12-16 17:19:42.061  15731-15731/com.zapk.lsmods V/GAV4﹕ Thread[main,5,main]: service connected, binder: android.os.BinderProxy@41546a38
12-16 17:19:42.061  15731-15731/com.zapk.lsmods V/GAV4﹕ Thread[main,5,main]: bound to service
12-16 17:19:42.061  15731-15731/com.zapk.lsmods V/GAV4﹕ Thread[main,5,main]: Connected to service
12-16 17:19:42.141  15731-15758/com.zapk.lsmods V/GAV4﹕ Thread[GAThread,5,main]: Sending hit to service   PATH: https:  PARAMS: v=1,  ul=en-gb,  t=screenview,  ht=1418743176826,  sr=540x960,  a=2025550344,  an=Farming simulator 15 mods,  tid=UA-57677772-1,  aid=com.zapk.lsmods,  cid=c892183c-7dbc-4170-b0c7-5f73fc0a820c,  av=1.0,  _u=.22nK-AL,  cd=MainActivity,
```

this is code for my AppController
  // The following line should be changed to include the correct property id.

```
   private static final String PROPERTY_ID = "UA-XXXX-1";

    public static int GENERAL_TRACKER = 0;
    public enum TrackerName {
        APP_TRACKER, // Tracker used only in this app.
        GLOBAL_TRACKER, // Tracker used by all the apps from a company. eg: roll-up tracking.
        ECOMMERCE_TRACKER, // Tracker used by all ecommerce transactions from a company.
    }

    public HashMap<TrackerName, Tracker> mTrackers = new HashMap<TrackerName, Tracker>();

    public AppController() {
        super();
    }

    private void initGoogleAnalytics() {
        GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
        analytics.setDryRun(false);
        analytics.setLocalDispatchPeriod(1);
        analytics.getLogger().setLogLevel(Logger.LogLevel.VERBOSE);
        analytics.enableAutoActivityReports(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        initGoogleAnalytics();
    }

    public synchronized Tracker getTracker(TrackerName trackerId) {
        if (!mTrackers.containsKey(trackerId)) {
            GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
            Tracker t = (trackerId == TrackerName.APP_TRACKER) ? analytics.newTracker(PROPERTY_ID): (trackerId == TrackerName.GLOBAL_TRACKER) ? analytics.newTracker(R.xml.global_tracker): analytics.newTracker(R.xml.ecommerce_tracker);
            mTrackers.put(trackerId, t);

        }
        return mTrackers.get(trackerId);
    }
```

And then I am calling analytics like this:

```
Tracker track = ((AppController)this.getApplication()).getTracker(AppController.TrackerName.APP_TRACKER);
        track.setScreenName("MainActivity");
        track.send(new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder().build());
```

this is code for my app_tracker xml file:

```
<string name="ga_trackingId">UA-XXXXX-1</string>

<bool name="ga_autoActivityTracking">true</bool>
<bool name="ga_reportUncaughtExceptions">true</bool>

<string name="ga_appName">Serivce</string>
<string name="ga_appVersion">1.1.3</string>

<bool name="ga_debug">true</bool>

<item name="ga_dispatchPeriod" format="integer" type="integer">120</item>

<string name="ga_sampleFrequency">90</string>


<bool name="ga_dryRun">false</bool>

<!-- Percentage of events to include in reports -->
<string name="ga_sampleFrequency">100.0</string>

<!-- How long a session exists before giving up -->
<integer name="ga_sessionTimeout">2000</integer>

<screenName name="com.zapk.lsmods.MainActivity">
    MainActivity
</screenName>
<screenName name="com.zapk.lsmods.MainFragment">
    AnalyticsSampleApp MainFragment
</screenName>
```

I mananged to get my hit sent one time, but I still couldnt see any information in my analytics dashboard.

Comment: Probably a dumb question but, without reading through that since I am no analytics pro, did you give it a minute? It takes a second to register on the dash.

Comment: I have actual analytics account for 4 years now, and I have added my app just yesterday. I was wondering if adding new profile also takes lots of hours to process?

Comment: The real time report can take up to 30 minutes to update. Full report can sometimes take up to 28h hours to show the data. Do you see the report after a day?

Comment: Btw you have ga_sampleFrequency defined twice in your tracker xml definition - once with 90 and once with 100.0. I'm not sure which one has precedence. If its the 90% sampling rate it might just happen that the device you are suing falls in the 10% that are sampled out and you will not see any data.